# Statement with or without variable in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

A while ago i was writing a code in python where I required to convert a list into a numpy array and do numpy operation (such as np.sum..)

```
a=[]
for i in range(2):
    a.append(i)
z = np.array(a)
print (np.sum(z))
```

In the line

```
z = np.array(a)
```

I interpret it as performing some action on a and then storing it in z and then printing it on screen

If I alternatively write the code

```
a=[]
for i in range(2):
    a.append(i)
np.array(a)
print (np.sum(a))
```

It still gives the same output. I don't know how does the computer interprets the line

```
np.array(a)
```

and perform the operation of

```
np.sum(a)
```

when I am not storing it in the variable like I did previously (in z).

Comment: try deleting the `np.array(a) ` line entirely and see what happens  :)

Answer (score 1):

numpy.sum can receive any array-like argument to sum (be it list or a numpy array).
So the line

```
np.sum(a)
```

will work with either a list argument or numpy array.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html

Comment: if it hadn't been the case ( if it only takes array), then would you think the second part would have worked

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh No, since "np.array(a)" won't store the result array anywhere, "a" will still point to the same list.

Answer (score 1):

```
z = np.array(a)
```

Creates a numpy array with the same size and values as `a`, then lets the variable `z` refer to that array.

```
np.array(a)
```

Creates a numpy array with the same size and values as `a`, then throws it away.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special here `np.sum` works on python lists too, and here `a` is a list.and lists are mutable objects and you appended some elements to it so after the loop the list `a` would be `[0, 1]`:

```
>>> a=[]
>>> for i in range(2):
...     a.append(i)
... 
>>> a
[0, 1]
```

and the following code returns a numpy array.

```
>>> np.array(a)
array([0, 1])
```

If instead of `sum()` function you want to use `array.sum` attribute of numpy arrays then you should converted your list to an array :

```
>>> a.sum()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'
>>> np.array(a).sum()
1
```

Comment: if it hadn't been the case ( if np.sum only took array), then would you think the second part would have worked